# Why are the buttons of the type submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, button

This is the html:

```
<button>Static</button>
<form>
<span id="test"> </span>
</form>
```

This is the jQuery - runs in the document.ready:

```
    $('#test').append('<button>Dynamic</button>');

    $('button').live('click', function(){
       alert($(this).attr('type')); 
    });

    //even this one:
    alert($('<button>test</button>').attr('type'));
```

The it alerts it says the 'type' is 'submit', but I haven't specified a type. How come? At least IE and Chrome are consequent in giving it the type "submit". But I don't even have a form, so it seems weird to make it a submit-button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value for the type attribute for `<button>` elements is defined as 'submit' in the specification.

> submit: Creates a submit button. This is the default value.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

Comment: Ah, same for HTML5: The missing value default is the Submit Button state. If the type attribute is in the Submit Button state, the element is specifically a submit button. (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-button-element). Thanks!